# Previously working database now startup in Postgresql 9.2

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I'm slowly teaching myself django and I'm using postgres 9.2

Previously, about 2 weeks ago, I had successfully installed and created my database via homebrew.

Now when I type

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I get this result

```
FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Invalid argument
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=32374784, 03600).
HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMMAX parameter.  You can either reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMMAX.  To reduce the request size (currently 32374784 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
If the request size is already small, it's possible that it is less than your kernel's SHMMIN parameter, in which case raising the request size or reconfiguring SHMMIN is called for.
The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.
```

Meanwhile, I did change the memory configuration in /ect/sysctl.conf and rebooted after the change - but I still get the same error.

Why is this happening and what do I do to stop it? (I'm using Mac OS X Mountain lion if this helps at all)

Comment: What is the value of `shared_buffers` in postgresql.conf

Comment: shared_buffers = 24MB   # min 128kB
     # (change requires restart)

Comment: weirdly it started working